# pnpm private workspace packages written in TypeScript: expose src or dist?

Tags: typescript, pnpm

I have a monorepo of mostly TypeScript code managed using pnpm, and we have lots of intra-workspace package dependencies (e.g. for library packages). These packages are private to this workspace and never published on their own. We typically define the package like so:

```json
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": ["dist"]
}
```

The problem with this is when you change something in a library. It's sort of annoying that the IDE won't see those those changes until the library is rebuilt. Because of this, I'm considering if we should instead just have the package expose the TypeScript source:

```json
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "files": ["src"]
}
```

This seems to work at first glance, but it also seems like it might be a bad idea. What are the downsides of this approach? Will the TypeScript source have unpredictable behavior because it would depend on the TypeScript tooling used by the depending package (e.g. foo-server uses TypeScript 4.7 and bar-server uses TypeScript 4.9, so they interpret the source of my-library differently)? Is there a better way to structure my workspace so that this doesn't happen?

If this is a bad idea, is there any other strategy people use to make the development experience have less friction? Or should I just suck it up and deal with it?

Comment: "_the IDE won't see those those changes until the library is rebuilt_" - what IDE is this? What changes are you referring to? What even does the `files` field of the package.json have to do with what is visible through the IDE?

Comment: I'm not even aware of TypeScript caring about the `files` field of package.json. The only field of package.json I'm aware of it caring about for the package of the project it's compiling for the purposes of compilation is the `type` field.

Comment: @user This is in vscode. I don't know that the `files` field is doing anything honestly. I'm trying to find the right combination of things to get reliable production builds and a pleasant development experience. What I'm taking from your comment is to maybe try setting `main` to `dist/index.js` and `types` to `src/index.ts`?

Comment: I'm still confused. What exactly do you mean by "_the IDE won't see those those changes until the library is rebuilt_"? What makes you think that? Are you referring to the compiled output not being updated until your re-run compilation? Because... yeah... that's normal.

Comment: @user I care less about the compiled files being up to date (when I want to run the application, I'll be recompiling anyways). But when I switch to code in another package that wants to use the new method I just added, and it doesn't see that it exists, then it's extra friction. I already wrote the code, the IDE should be able to see the interfaces exist (even if it the implementation hasn't been built yet). If there's a solution that solves this for compilation and IDE both, that's great, but I don't care much about the compilation part.

Comment: can you please add code and config for a [mre]?